# Ingress rule using host

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, microk8s

Can someone please help to spot the issue with `ingress-2` ingress rule? why `ingress-1` is working vs `ingress-2` is not working.

**Description of my setup, I have two deployments:**

1st deployment is of `nginx`
2nd deployment is of `httpd`

Both of the deployments are exposed via `ClusterIP` services named `nginx-svc` and `httpd-svc` respectively. All the `endpoints` are proper for the services. However, while
setting up the ingress for these services, I am not able to setup the ingress using `host` (as described in `ingress-2`). however, when I am using `ingress-1`, things work fine.

// my host file for name resolution

```
grep myapp.com /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1        myapp.com
```

// deployment details

```
kubectl get deployments.apps
NAME    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx   3/3     3            3           29m
httpd   3/3     3            3           29m
```

// service details

```
kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP   7h48m
nginx-svc    ClusterIP   10.152.183.233   <none>        80/TCP    28m
httpd-svc    ClusterIP   10.152.183.58    <none>        80/TCP    27m
```

// endpoints details

```
kubectl get ep
NAME         ENDPOINTS                                      AGE
kubernetes   10.0.2.15:16443                                7h51m
nginx-svc    10.1.198.86:80,10.1.198.87:80,10.1.198.88:80   31m
httpd-svc    10.1.198.89:80,10.1.198.90:80,10.1.198.91:80   31m
```

Attempt-1: `ingress-1`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-svc
            port:
              number: 80

      - path: /httpd
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: httpd-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

// Example showing that ingress routing is working fine when `ingress-1` is used:

```
 curl myapp.com/nginx
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>


 curl myapp.com/httpd
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

// following ingress rule is not working as I was expecting

Attempt-2: `ingress-2`

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "myapp.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/nginx"
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/httpd"
        backend:
          service:
            name: httpd-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

// I could not spot any issue in the ing describe

```
kubectl describe  ingress ingress-2
Name:             ingress-2
Namespace:        default
Address:          127.0.0.1
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host          Path  Backends
  ----          ----  --------
  myapp.com
                /nginx   nginx-svc:80 (10.1.198.86:80,10.1.198.87:80,10.1.198.88:80)
                /httpd   httpd-svc:80 (10.1.198.89:80,10.1.198.90:80,10.1.198.91:80)
Annotations:    <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                  From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                 ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    9m15s (x2 over 10m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

// example showing ingress routing is not working with this ingress resource

```
curl myapp.com/nginx
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.1</center>
</body>
</html>

curl myapp.com/httpd
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: What kind of kubernetes cluster are you using? I guess it's `k3s` based on service endpoints. Also which ingress is used on cluster? Default `traefik`? Also if you delete the second ingress rule and apply the first one, does it still work?

Comment: I am using `microk8s` in a vm.  It uses `nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-sgnxq`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Difference between ingresses

I created a one node `microk8s` cluster [following official documentation](https://microk8s.io/) and I wasn't able to reproduce behaviour you described which is correct behaviour. Added two pods with `mendhak/http-https-echo` image (highly recommend: very convenient for troubleshooting ingress or understanding how ingress works) and two services for each of pods.

The difference between two ingress rules is first ingress rule listens on all domains (HOSTS):

```
$ mkctl get ing -o wide
NAME        CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
ingress-1   public   *       127.0.0.1   80      2m53s

$ curl -I --header "Host: myapp.com" http://127.0.0.1/httpd
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

$ curl -I --header "Host: example.com" http://127.0.0.1/httpd
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

$ curl -I --header "Host: myapp.com" http://127.0.0.1/missing_url
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

While the second ingress rule will serve only `myapp.com` domain (HOST):

```
$ mkctl get ing
NAME        CLASS    HOSTS       ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
ingress-2   public   myapp.com   127.0.0.1   80      60s

$ curl -I --header "Host: myapp.com" http://127.0.0.1/httpd
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

$ curl -I --header "Host: example.com" http://127.0.0.1/httpd
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

### What exactly happens

Last results in your question actually show that ingress is working as expected. You're getting responses not from `kubernetes ingress` but from pods within the cluster. First response is `404` from `nginx 1.21.0` and second is `404` from `apache`.

This happens because ingress sends requests to pods with the same `path` from URL without any transformations. For instance (this output I got using image mentioned above):

```
$ curl myapp.com/httpd
{
  "path": "/httpd"
...
```

While both `nginx` and `apache` are serving on `/`.

### How to resolve it

Nginx ingress has a lot of features and one of them is [rewriting](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) which helps to transform `paths` from what ingress gets to what goes to pods.

For example, if request goes to `http://myapp.com/nginx` then it will be directed to `nginx` service with `/nginx` path which will cause `nginx` to throw `404` since there's nothing on this `path`.

Ingress rule below fixes this by adding `rewrite-target` to `/` which we need to pass to `nginx` and `apache` services:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-2
  annotations:
#    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx # this should be uncommented if ingress used in "regular" cluster
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service-a
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /httpd
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service-b
            port:
              number: 80
```

Quick test how it works:

```
$ curl myapp.com/nginx
{
  "path": "/",
...
```

And

```
$ curl myapp.com/httpd
{
  "path": "/",
...
```

As you can see now `path` is `/`.

Switching image to `nginx` and:

```
$ curl myapp.com/nginx
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
...
```

### Useful links

- [Kubernetes ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)
- [Nginx ingress - rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)

Comment: thank you for wonderful explanation, this perfectly explain what was fundamentally wrong in my attempts. one question, why you had to use `curl -I --header "Host: myapp.com" http://127.0.0.1/httpd` ? (supplying hostname in header ? why not just `curl -I http://myapp.com/httpd` ?

Comment: never mind, I figured that out.  This answer deserve more upvotes :)